Cooking lasagna in a circle dutch oven?
I don't own a casserole dish to make lasagna and was curious if anyone has tried to make lasagna with circular pot? I plan on after cooking the pasta cutting into shape when layering. I should mention that I have not made lasagna before.

Do a search for "pan lasagna" recipe and you'll see the gamut from loaf pans to Bundt pans to sheet pans. Lasagna is pretty forgiving - as long as the noodles have something on them so they don't dry out, pretty much any heat-safe container will work if you don't go too hot to start and leave enough time to warm up.

I suspect that “pan lasagna” may include other stuff.  In the US, I would recommend the term “ skillet lasagna”

You'll also want to plan to have an excess of noodles, since there will be a lot of loss inherent in cutting circles.

I doubt the shape of the dish makes that much difference, assuming that you adjust for the difference in area - if you'll be piling a recipe that's designed for a large shallow rectangular pan into a smaller round pan, much deeper, there would likely be an effect on cooking time from the added depth.
If you scale the recipe from the bottom area of the dish called for to the bottom area of the dish you have, it should end up the same depth and cook pretty much the same. You won't have somewhat more crispy corners, since you don't have corners; which is good or bad depending on if you or someone you're serving particularly seeks out corner sections of lasagna casserole. I don't happen to know anyone who seems to care that much about the location of their slice, so I doubt it's a major issue. But I'd not be surprised if some people did care, one way or the other.
